# Can I specify a prerequisite that is run before every target in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am new to Makefiles. I would like to run a simple command (just to set the terminal title) when `make` is invoked, regardless of the `make` target.

I don't want to have to repeatedly specify the command to run in front of every target (my makefile has lots and lots of targets and I don't want to repeat myself). Eg, I don't want to have to do:

```
some-target: command-to-run-before-target:
   actual-recipe

some-other-target: command-to-run-before-target
   other-actual-recipe
```

But instead I'd like something like:

```
magic-dependency-for-every-target:
   command-to-run-before-target
```

I have read the [Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Introduction.html#Rule-Introduction) but I can't see a way to do this - I probably don't know what to search for.

Comment: It is not possible.